# How to debug PHP code in Visual Studio Code in the services of XAMPP?

Tags: php, debug, xampp, visual-studio-code

First, I turned on XAMPP and started the following services:

[image: The services that I started in XAMPP - screenshot]

By the way, the PHP Version is 7.3.3. Then I checked `phpinfo()` in the browser. Here is a screenshot:

[image: phpinfo() - screenshot]

And I went [xdebug.org](https://xdebug.org/download.php) to download this version of Xdebug:

[image: The Xdebug version I've downloaded - screenshot]

When I copied this file to `C:\xampp\php\ext`, I found there is a file named `php_xdebug.dll`. Whatever, I still called the Xdebug file into the path without its name changed (`php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll`).

Next, I copied a piece of code into `php.ini` from an article on the Internet:

```
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.2-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

But I couldn't figure out why the port was 9000 and the port didn't work at all. I entered `localhost:9000` in the address bar of Chrome and the results page shows that localhost rejected my connection request.

However, I still went on. I installed the "PHP Debug" extension in VS Code. The extension's `launch.json` is shown below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Finally, I created a new PHP file and debugged it. When I opened the file in the browser, the debug program didn't work. So, could you please tell me where the problem is and show me the exact debugging steps?

---

update:
Finally, I found what the problem is, the 9000 port number is occupied! So I typed ‘netstat -ano’ in cmd and found port 9000 and the corresponding PID value. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APEci.png)Then type 'taskkill /PID 4380 /F' to kill the process that occupies the port. Finally, restart the PHP services. Thus, this issue has been solved. But remember, make sure you install the correct xdebug version, which you can view in XAMPP's phpinfo().
Thanks to the friends in the comment area for your help.

Comment: Did you restart XAMPP (i.e. reload PHP in the server)? Likewise, does an `Xdebug` section show up when you run `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Compare your installation with [this cookbook](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2016/02/11/configuring-visual-studio-code-for-php-development/).

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to open 9000 port, you just run debug like:

[image]

then

[image]

choose PHP

[image]

start and play green icon

[image]

add break point into your methods or controllers

[image]

manage your breakpoints

[image]

Comment: My "Listen for XDebug" configuration was set to port 9003 for some reason, changing to 9000 (defined in php.ini: `xdebug.remote_port = 9000`) fixed it!